# codeigniter session attribute's value passed as text

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

basically i am working on a kind-of E-commerce website.
Now, the problem i have is that i have a database table with fieldname="fldRateMB1" and have other database tables with fieldnames similar with just slight change i.e. fldRateMB2, fldRateRH1 and likewise and i use a template where i display this field the code being as under.

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
..............
<td><input type="text" name="rate_<?php echo $id;?>" value="<?php echo $product->fldRateMB1;?>" id="rate_<?php echo $id;?>" /></td>
..............
```

now what i want to do is use a session parameter to do the naming thing i.e. i want to set the value fldRateMB1 or fldRateRH1 through session via links i click on

```
<?php 
class Director extends CI_Controller{
function index(){
$newdata = array('venue_id' => 'fldRateMB1');//Add venue's id and name into session data
$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
redirect(base_url('shop'));
    }
  }
?>
```

and use it some way on the display page I tried following some of them may seem stupid

```
value="<?php echo $product->$this->session->userdata('venue_id');?>"
```

or

```
$rate=$this$this->session->userdata('venue_id');
value="<?php echo $product->$rate";?>
```

Comment: This might work but have you tried it??

Comment: // try this //  $rate=$this->session->userdata('venue_id');
value="<?php echo $rate; ?>"

Comment: Naah.. its too complex then u think it is..thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

got it your mistake is 
when you are setting session set don't set like this

```
$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

try this

```
$this->session->set_userdata('venue_id' ,$newdata);
```

and in html replace

value="$this->session->userdata('venue_id');?>"

with

```
value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('venue_id');?>"
```

for further information check
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Ijaz bhai you didn't understand my problem, the solution you suggest would display value of 'venue_id' which is "fldRateMB1" and what i wanna print is the data stored in the field fldRateMB1 in the products database which is a numerical value e.g. '30'.

Comment: well i have suggest you the path to follow

Comment: you were not setting the data in session properly now you can set data in session like that and retrieve as in html shown just print that value it would be in array just modify that accordingly